# Hybrid Cloud vs Federated Cloud

Tags: cloud

Is there any difference between Hybrid Cloud and Federated Cloud?

As well I read a lot the word "Intercloud". I understand it as a vision of several huge federated clouds each for special purposes. Is that right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [cloud computing](http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/cloud-computing) continues to gain in popularity, people are also looking for ways to make the cloud fit their own personal or organizational needs. As more changes occur, people are trying to decide what kind of cloud they should use, and one of the decisions they must make includes whether to use a hybrid cloud or a federated cloud, or whether to use public clouds. One question that more and more people ask is if there is a difference between federated clouds and hybrid clouds as they seem to be more and more interchangeable.
A federated cloud is an amalgam of several internal and external clouds that are put together to meet an individual, or a business’s needs. Just as in the political science definition of federation, a federated cloud is the joining or the union of several smaller parts in order to perform together to accomplish one particular and specific action.

Similarly, a hybrid cloud is using “the cloud” in a way that an organization or business manages some of the cloud resources in-house, while other resources come from external sources. An organization may use a public cloud service to archive older data, but they may use in-house cloud storage for customer information that is more up-to-date. Using a hybrid cloud system allows things that are perhaps less important to be stored in the less expensive public sector of cloud computer, while maintaining the more sensitive information and data internally. By keeping the less sensitive material internal, it is more protected from outsiders hacking into the information.

Ultimately, there is no difference between federated and hybrid clouds. Both terms discuss the joining of internal and outside clouds in order to accomplish one goal. Term federated cloud has been around longer, but as time goes by, the term hybrid cloud has been used more to describe the accomplishing the same task. The terms and hybrid and federated are just different names that describe the same process or existing practice to make it more universally understood by practitioners.

http://content.dell.com/us/en/enterprise/cloud-computing

Answer (score 1):

Both are inter-connected cloud approaches. The basic difference is: cloud federation is a volunteer organization.  The clouds know than is part of the organization. In this way the cloud respect one internal sla contract. Hybrid user is a user organization where public resource when they are attractive or necessary, in other words, the public cloud doesn't know that part of the organization multi-cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Federated Cloud is a therm that describes solution caused by needs more than security or policy, where Hybrid Cloud is better adopted. In example You can use MS SQL as a serviuce in Microsoft Azure (SQL Azure) because of SLA, scalability, backup or disaster recovery and hosting Your application in Heroku, because it is a Ruby app and You really like to develop on Heroku. You can also use Big Table in Google and Hadoop in Azure, making backups to Amazon. This is a federated cloud.
If You have Your own, private cloud with (let say) customers databases or medical data and You do not want or cannot put it to the public cloud, but there is no problem with using public cloud for workloads in analysis - it is a hybrid cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are. Federated cloud is, in a nutshell, a model that offers different services from different vendors. in another words, you may call it a multi-cloud environment. Cloud computing has come a long way recently and therefore both of the models are getting more 'enriched', let's put it that way. So by using APIs, cloud clients can now adjust their cloud plan using different service vendors - all at once, according to their needs.

Hybrid cloud is a bit different. Technically, a hybrid cloud would combine a private cloud interface along with a public cloud interface - mostly used by large organizations, having the public cloud concept using few components drawn from the public cloud concept. A good example for that concept would be Stratoscale, which my organization's been using for some time now. They are a good example of a hybrid cloud, providing "holistic" cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

hybrid cloud is a cloud computing that formed by different cloud models( Private and public clouds). whereas federated cloud is formed by different cloud models(public and private clouds) as well as the same clouds ( Joint private clouds). what ever it is both hybrid and federated cloud have the same concept. both are made a single cloud by joining together to achieve the specific goals.